# Regex Ignore numbers in a string (python)

Tags: python, regex, string, numbers

I have a text like this :

```
text = "hey , i am new here . number is 8,5%"
```

And i want my output to be like this :

```
hey, i am new here. number is 8,5%
```

So am using this regex code :

```
text= re.sub(r'\s*([.,?:])\s*', r'\1 ',text)
```

The output of this code is :

```
hey, i am new here. number is , 5%
```

I don't want the numbers to be touched with my regex code.

Am using Python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\s*([?:]|(?<!\d)[.,](?!\d))\s*', r'\1 ',text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/q3dvp9) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gqthry/1).

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([?:]|(?<!\d)[.,](?!\d))` - Group 1:

  - `[?:]` - a `?` or `:`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<!\d)[.,](?!\d)` - a `.` or `,` not preceded nor followed with a digit
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(?<!\d)\s*([.,?:])\s*`.
`(?<!\d)` means "If not preceded by a digit"

Full piece of code:
`text= re.sub(r'\s*([.,?:])\s*', r'\1 ',text)`